# Command line to produce beginning of lines

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I have a file that has the format

```
string string string ...
string string string ...
...
string string string ...
```

I want to get another file, so that for each line, only the first `string` appears in that line (i.e. take only the part before the first whitespace of each line.)

How could I do that with commandline in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
awk '{print $1}' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Its basic functionality is very easy to learn. For instance, in order to print the first two columns of a file and their sum you could do `{print $1 " " $2 " " $1+$2}`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is to use cut:

```
cut -f1 -d" " input.txt > output.txt
```